# Which is the recommended way to read tagged objects with JOOQ?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

For adding tags to objects in a database, it seems to be a common approach to have the following scheme:

There is the entity which has some attributes and a lot of tags which can be added to them.
Lets say there are three tables:

the table Element with the columns ID and NAME (and some other values),
 the table Tags with the columns TAGID and TAGNAME and 
 the table TagsToElement with TAGID and ELEMENTID which assigns the Tags to the Elements.

I wonder, which is a good way to read Elements from the database which have a specific tag assigned to them. I mean, how would a Condition from Jooq look like to filter out only the ELements which have a specific tag assigned.

Is this possible with only one access to the database?

Greetings

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always with [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), the question you should ask yourself first is: "How would I write this in SQL?". In SQL, you'd write

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   Element
WHERE  EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   Tags
  JOIN   TagsToElement
  ON     Tags.TAGID = TagsToElement.TAGID
  WHERE  Element.ID = TagsToElement.ELEMENTID
  AND    Tags.TAGNAME = 'Specific Name'
)
```

Translate the above 1:1 to jOOQ:

```java
// import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*; is assumed
DSL.using(configuration)
   .selectFrom(Element)
   .whereExists(
      selectOne()
     .from(Tags)
     .join(TagsToElement)
     .on(Tags.TAGID.eq(TagsToElement.TAGID))
     .where(Element.ID.eq(TagsToElement.ELEMENTID))
     .and(Tags.TAGNAME.eq("Specific Name"))
   )
```

Obviously, you could express your semi-join also with an `IN` predicate rather than with an `EXISTS` predicate.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer.

I try to keep the structure for reading Elements like this:

create.select(fields).from(table).where(conditions).fetch();

Where fields is a set of fields, table a set of tables and conditions a set of Conditions.

The Elements can be filtered out by several attributes.
So I create the matching Conditions an add them to the set.

Is there a way to create a Condition for the filtering by tagname?

Greetings 

Mike

Comment: @user1817612: Stack Overflow comments are not the best way to explain such things. They tend to get quite lengthy. Why not accept this answer and ask a new question about creating a condition?